# Changing variable names when inheriting from another class Python

Tags: python, variables, inheritance, typeerror

I have wrote a class called Ratios that inherits from the class LatticeParam. In the class Ratios I want to rename the the variables `a,b,c` upon inheriting them. I have tried to solve this with `**kwargs`, but I receive the error message:

> TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'a'.

Below, I have posted a small part of the code. Is it possible to change the variable names this way, or am I on the wrong track? Thanks in advance!

```
class LatticeParam():
    def __init__(self, a = None, b = None, c = None, error_a = None, error_b = None, error_c = None, x = None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.error_a = error_a
        self.error_b = error_b
        self.error_c = error_c
        self.x = x

class Ratios(LatticeParam):
    def __init__(self, a_O = None, b_O = None, c_O = None, a_H = None, b_H = None, c_H = None, error_a_ = None, error_b_ = None, error_c_ = None, x_ = None):
        super().__init__(self, a = a_O, b = b_O, c = c_O, error_a = error_a_, error_b = error_b_, error_c = error_c_, x = x_)
        self.a_H = a_H
        self.b_H = b_H
        self.c_H = c_H
        self.abratio = [i/j for i,j in zip(self.a_O, self.b_O)]
        self.acratio = [i/j for i,j in zip(self.a_H, self.c_H)]
```

Edit: code for calling Ratios is:

```
#Orthorhombic Phase
a_O = [5.89560, 5.89286, 5.84324, 5.85336, 5.81866] #006, 008, 010, 012, 014
b_O = [3.61421, 3.61502, 3.63846, 3.65832, 3.65826]
c_O = [6.90838, 6.90561, 6.93348, 6.95762, 6.95347]

#Hexagonal Phase
a_H = [4.79468, 4.79103, 4.78724, 4.79317, 4.79322] #006, 008, 010, 012, 014
b_H = [4.79468, 4.79103, 4.78724, 4.79317, 4.79322]
c_H = [7.43995, 7.43580, 7.433733, 7.44091, 7.43372]

#Error
error_a = [0.00014, 0.00012, 0.00007, 0.00014, 0.00012] #006, 008, 010, 012 014
error_b = [0.00010, 0.00006, 0.00008, 0.00007, 0.00012]
error_c = [0.00013, 0.00012, 0.00004, 0.00017, 0.00024]
error_VO = [0.006, 0.005, 0.003, 0.006, 0.006] #006 008 010 012 014
x_OH = [0.06, 0.08, 0.10, 0.12, 0.14]

RATIO = PD.Ratios(a_O, b_O, c_O, a_H, b_H, c_H, error_a, error_b, error_c, x_OH)
```

Comment: Where is the use of `**kwargs` that you mention in the question?

Comment: Why? If an instance of `Ratios` doesn't have instance attributes `a` et al., you are breaking the invariant that an instance of `Ratios` can be used anywhere an instant of `LatticeParam` is expected.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass `self` to `super().__init__`; passing that extra arg is causing it to be interpreted positionally as `a`, which is what causes that error.

After that, you need to actually define `self.a_O` etc, since changing the kwarg name doesn't automagically change the attribute name.  If you want them to just be an alias for the parent class's `a`, you could define a property:

```
class Ratios(LatticeParam):
    def __init__(self, a_O = None, b_O = None, c_O = None, a_H = None, b_H = None, c_H = None, error_a_ = None, error_b_ = None, error_c_ = None, x_ = None):
        super().__init__(a = a_O, b = b_O, c = c_O, error_a = error_a_, error_b = error_b_, error_c = error_c_, x = x_)
        self.a_H = a_H
        self.b_H = b_H
        self.c_H = c_H
        self.abratio = [i/j for i,j in zip(self.a_O, self.b_O)]
        self.acratio = [i/j for i,j in zip(self.a_H, self.c_H)]

    @property
    def a_O(self):
        return self.a

    @property
    def b_O(self):
        return self.b
```

"Renaming" parent attributes like this seems like a bad design pattern, though, and I would suggest not doing it.  I would need to know more about your motivations for this in order to suggest a good alternative.

Comment: I suppose the use case could be like Square inheriting from Rectangle, and renaming `length` and `width` to `side`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply! The reason I want to change the names is that in the class LatticeParam() I plot the variables a,b,c from 1 group against eachother (so either a_o, b_o and c_o or a_h, b_h and c_h) and in the Ratios class I want to plot a_o/b_o and a_h/c_h together, so 2 groups.

Comment: It seems like it might make more sense for the Ratios class to compose two LatticeParam objects.